# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

Tags: sql, vb.net

I always got an error when adding a new data. the error says

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated

As I've looked back on my backend or code. It looks like there's a conflict adding a `TWO LABEL DATA` in one column because I would like to join the (Year)-(StudentNumber)

Here's the code of my INSERT INTO Statement

```
  INSERT INTO
     [Student_Information] (StudentID, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Gender, 
                            ContactNumber, Citizenship, Religion, Birthday, Address) 
  VALUES 
     ( '" & lbl_cyear.Text - studid.Text & "','" + txt_lname.Text + "', '" + txt_fname.Text + "', '" + txt_mname.Text + "', '" + DDGender.Text + "', '" & txt_cnumber.Text & "', '" & txt_citizenship.Text & "' , '" + txt_religion.Text + "' , '" & txt_bday.Text & "', '" & txt_address.Text & "' )"
```

and here's the code how I generate the Year and the Student Number

```
Sub SNYear()
    Dim test As Date

    test = Convert.ToDateTime(Today)
    lbl_cyear.Text = test.Year
End Sub
Sub SNGenerate()
    'displaying Studentid
    Dim SN As Integer ' Student Number
    Dim SID As String 'Student ID Num as String

    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader

    cmd1.Connection = cn
    cmd1.Connection.Open()
    cmd1.CommandText = "Select Max (StudentID) as expr1 from [Student_Information]"
    rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader

    If rdr.HasRows = True Then
        rdr.Read()
    End If

    If rdr.Item(0).ToString = Nothing Then
        SN = rdr.Item(0) + 1
        SID = Format(SN, "0000")
    ElseIf rdr.Item(0).ToString = 0 Then
        SN = rdr.Item(0) + 1
        SID = Format(SN, "0000")

    Else
        SN = rdr.Item(0) + 1
        SID = Format(SN, "0000")
    End If


    studid.Text = SID

    cmd1.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

Can someone help me with the code? How to join 2 data in different label text and save it to one column in my table.

Comment: Retagged this question for you. The problem has to do with Visual Basic and SQL - not ASP.NET at all.

Comment: Did you mean to set `StudentID` to `lbl_cyear.Text - studid.Text`?

Answer (score 8):

Woah! Never ever write sql queries like that. It's subject to dangerous SQL injection, and code like that is actually used as worst-case scenarios in SQL injection lectures everywhere!

That being said, the error message **String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.** actually spells out what is wrong. You are trying to insert too much data into a field that has a specific dimension.

You are trying to insert the following expression into the `StudentID` field:

```
lbl_cyear.Text - studid.Text
```

I'm not even sure what you want to do there. Since Visual Basic is loosely typed by default, It will probably handle the `lbl_cyear.Text` as a number and try to subtract the `studid.Text` *(as a number)* from it. You probably mean something like this:

```
lbl_cyear.Text & "-" & studid.Text
```

It seems you are trying to use the `StudentID` column for two different types of information. Don't do that. Decide on one format for the student ids and dimension the column for it.

Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Yes it is a homework. Btw, im using "-" for separation not for operation. As what the requirements said. The student number should be composed by "Year - Student Number " then what should I do. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, but the way your code is written, it **is** an operation. To help you move on with this, there are lots of little things that you should look at, and it takes a different setting than a stackoverflow question...

Answer (score 3):

Y@atornblad has some very valid points about re-structuring your code. However, the specific problem you are asking about is likely because you are trying to insert data into a column that is longer than the column can accept.

E.g. - you are trying to insert "Lorem Ipsum" into a column that has a maximum length of 5 characters.

**Edit** 
You need to take another look at how your table is defined and make sure it is appropriate for the data you are storing. Also - make sure the data you are trying to store is in the correct format that the table was designed for. Don't assume it's in the format you want, actually step through the program in debug mode and look at what the variable is before it gets sent to the database.

Comment: Precisely but I've got a maximum length of 50 character and the value I only entered is about 9 characters :\